# Communication between expressjs and angular2

Tags: angular, http, express, mean

I am little bit confused. Currently I am creating MEAN app. I would like to know what is proper way to use expressJS and Angular2 together? Do I really need view engine in backend side?

Currently in my project router is redirecting to index.hbs ( i am using handlebars view engine):

```
 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        res.render('index');
});
```

Then index.hbs is loading angular2 :

```
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
```

It is working, but I am wondering if I really need that index.hbs file? Will it be better to create separate frontend with own index.html and backend responsible only for responding on HTTP requests (without view engine)?

Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular as the frontend you don't need a view engine like handlebars or ejs.

Angular is used to build Single Page Applications (SPA). This means, that you deliver the whole application from the backend to the client on request.
The SPA then just reaches out to the backend to fetch dynamic data.

On a view engine like handlebars you have a page request for every single page change.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use Angular inside express js. you can keep both separated.

if you use Angular inside handlebar then for each render it will generate the page again which is not the purpose of Angular.

you can separate backend from angular

backend side you can implement api 
ex : for a module

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.indexRequest = function (req, res, next) {
    ... your implementation 
    res.status(response.statusCode).send(responseObject);
}
module.exports = function (app) {
app.use('/', router.indexRequest);}
```

Comment: Well, that approach was presented by Udemy on MEAN course, so is it really bad? Here is repo: [LINK](https://github.com/danielu221/MEAN-messenger)

Answer (score 0):

*"Do I really need view engine in backend side?"*

Short answer is: **Yes**.

View engine is necessary for any serious web application. Without view engine, there is no way to implement Server Side Rendering. As both Server Side Rendering (SSR) and Single Page Applications (SPA) are necessary for a good web application, view engine and frontend framework (AngularJS, React etc.) should be used at the same time.

For example, if you want to display "Login | Signup" when user is not logged in, and display username information when user is logged in. Without Server Side Rendering, you have to send 1 Ajax request to server and render the page according to the Ajax response -- the Ajax request will take some time and the corresponding page area would be blank until the response is received. This is certainly not a user-friendly behaviour.

Moreover, in one page, if you want to display area A, B, C, D when user's role is X, and display area B,D,E,F when user's role is Y, and display... Without Server Side Rendering, it would be a nightmare -- The final page structure would not be decided before the Ajax response with user-role is received.

Of course, if all you need is "Learning AngularJS", it's OK to ignore view engine. But if you are developing a product, or want to learn what a serious web application would look like, you really need view engine. I believe that's why Udemy includes view engine in their course.

If Server Side Rendering is used together with Single Page Application, to prevent those server-rendered-content from destroying SPA application logic, you can render the data in a script element. Here is a simple example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.userRoles = {= userRolesVar =} // {= =} is view engine tag and would be replaced by corresponding data during render.
</script>
```

In this way, `userRoles` data is returned at the very beginning and can be used by SPA framework such as AngularJS. No Ajax request is needed, and such server-render logic won't impact any SPA code.

---

@Ma Kobi For AngularJS SPA application, you are right on "the whole web application is deliver from backend to client". However, some server-rendered data (user roles etc.) should be sent to client together with the application.

Also, using view engine does not mean you have to send HTTP request for every single page change. After SPA is running, except the initial server-rendered data (example above), it has nothing to do with Server Side Rendering again.

---

@Gourav Soni you can use AngularJS together with Handlebar, it won't reload the page every time when page is re-rendered. Separate frontend from backend is a correct design, but it doesn't mean view engine should be discarded.